# Is it correct to do 1-to-1 mapping in Update API request param

Tags: api, rest

There is a need for me to do bulk update of user details.
Let the object details have the following fields,

1. User First Name
2. User ID
3. User Last Name
4. User Email ID
5. User Country

An admin can upload the updated data of the users through a csv file. Values with mismatching data needs to be updated. The most probable request format for this bulk update request will be like:(Method 1)

```
"data" : {
    "userArray" : [
        {
            "id" : 2343565432,
            "f_name" : "David",
            "email" : "david@testmail.com"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2344354351,
            "country" : "United States",
        }
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Method 2 : I would send the details in two arrays, one containing the list of similar filed values with respect to their user ids

```
"data" : {
    "userArray" : [
        {
            "ids" : [23234323432, 4543543543, 45654543543],
            "country" : ["United States", "Israel", "Mexico"]
        },
        {
            "ids" : [2323432334543, 567676565],
            "email" : ["groove@drivein.com", "zara@foobar.com"]
        },
        .
        .
        .

    ]
}
```

In method 1, i need to query the database for every user update, which will be more as the no of user edited is more. In contrast, if i use method 2, i query the database only once for each param(i add the array in the query and get those rows whose user id is present in the given array in a single query). And then i can update the each row with their respective details.

But overall in the internet, most of the update api had params in the format specified in method 1 which gives user good readability. But i need to know what will be advantage if i go with method 1 rather than method 2? (I save some query time in method 2 if the no of users count is large which can improve my performance)

Answer (score 0):

I almost always see it being method 1 style.

Woth that said, I don't understand why your DB performance is based on the way the input data is structured.  That's just the way information gets into your code.

You can have the client send the data as method 1 and then shim it to method 2 on the backend if that helps you structure the DB queries better

Comment: I use Java and MySQL. I don't work with result sets rather i have a Wrapper Class for my result set. Each update query is costly(as in performance-wise, primarily due to my wrapper class). So I prefer usually to do bulk update. This is the reason why my my DB performance is based on the input data.  To answer your second question, I have two layer communication, one for client to my application server(where the authorisation is evaluated, send in format 1) and two, from my app server to another application where the data is updated(need to decide the format).

Comment: Also, if the number of fields and users details altered increases, the JSON grows vertically(in method 2) and horizontally(in method 1). Will that have any effect on my performance? @AsadAwadia